# Is there a way to apply a Type selector to an element?

Tags: html, css, razor

I have a link which I want to appear like  a button.
I already have a style in the form of a Type selector 'button' and this is used all over.
Can I apply this to my link through HTML?

Razor:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Search", "Search", "N", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "NDiv", HttpMethod = "Post", OnComplete = "OnComplete" }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "button" })
```

CSS:

```
button {
        background-color: #d3dce0;
        border: 1px solid #787878;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 7px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        width: auto;
    }
```

I know I can duplicate the style and change the name to '.button' but I don't want to dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to duplicate the style.  You can simply add more elements to which the existing style is applied:

```
button, .button {
    background-color: #d3dce0;
    border: 1px solid #787878;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only viable solution to this really would be to do:

```
button, .button {
    background-color: #d3dce0;
    border: 1px solid #787878;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 7px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    width: auto;
}
```